# How to specify the target runtimes for a self-contained cross-platform .NET Core app?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, runtime-identifier

I have a .NET Core console app and want to make it a self-contained app that targets Windows and Mac OS X.

The way to do it, according to a tutorial that I'm following, is to edit the project file.

To make it a self-contained Windows only app, I add this line.

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

This works as expected, and I can publish the app and everything works. Now, to target Mac OS X as well as Windows, according to the tutorial, you need to change that line like this.

```
<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.12-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
```

However, when I put that in and try to save the changes to the project file, I run into the following error(s).

Related to Debug folder:

> The "HasTrailingSlash" function only accepts a scalar value, but its
>   argument "$(OutputPath)" evaluates to
>   "bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64;osx.10.12-x64\" which is not a
>   scalar value. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Related to Release folder:

> The "HasTrailingSlash" function only accepts a scalar value, but its
>   argument "$(OutputPath)" evaluates to
>   "bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64;osx.10.12-x64\" which is not a
>   scalar value. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

The project file is still saved, once I get away from all the warnings. They appear several times. Specifically, 4 warnings about debug path and 2 about release path (number of save attempts?).

[image]
[image]

When I close the solution and then open it again, this particular project refuses to load. It just sits in Solution Explorer as a project that's not loaded.

[image]

If I try to reload it I get a nice little red, critical error icon along with the same message.

[image]

Why is this happening, what seems to be the problem? Please advise, what's the appropriate way to target both Windows and Mac OS X for self-contained deployment on a Windows machine?

Is editing the project file still a valid approach? The tutorial I am following was released in August 2017 by a "software architect and developer with a passion for the cloud". He did comment on his approach of editing the project file, calling the current tooling "wonky".

### Update

---

`<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.12-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>`

This is **not** what I had typed in.

Instead, this is what I had in my code. Notice the singular form.

`<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64;osx.10.12-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

The problem lies in that I did not pay attention, nor did I type it in manually. I used code auto-completion (IntelliSense) and just tabbed through these tags.

Comment: According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-vs#simpleSelf) this is in fact how you do it, I don't see how what I did differs from what they describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### One RID

For only one runtime identifier (RID), you can use either the singular or the plural form of the XML runtime identifier tag.

`<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>`

OR

`<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>`

### Multiple RIDs

For more than one RID, you have to use the plural form of the XML runtime identifier tag.

`<RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;osx.10.12-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>`